# Will tomcat create an unlimited number of handling threads?

Tags: tomcat, threadpool

I was recently notified by sysadmin about a large amount of system threads created by a tomcat instance. The performance graph showed that from a particular point in time the number of threads started to grow constantly and eventually stopped at around 2500.

I checked though the web app and there are no obvious thread leaks, so the threads must be created by tomcat or the database connection pool.

I then discovered a dead lock in the code which will prevent threads from being returned to the thread pools, but I am still not sure how tomcat is able to create so many threads in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, there is limit... http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html (by default 200)

What kind of threads are created? Threads waiting for HTTP requests?

You should try to connect in to the server in debug and take a thread dump to wonder where the threads are stuck and what kind of threads are created.

HIH